# Python 3 encoding or errors without a string argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a function in **Python 2** which I used to generate a 22 length random string from a UUID....

```
def make_base64_string():
    return uuid.uuid4().bytes.encode("base64")[:22]
```

I have since started to test in Python 3 and just finished watching the [Pragmatic Unicode presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), most of which went way over my head. Anyway, I didn't assume this function would now work in Python 3.4 and I was right....

So next, I tried what I was hoping was the solution giving that `bytes.encode` from my understating is gone... (treat everything as a byte, right?).

```
base64.b64encode(bytes(uuid.uuid4(), 'utf-8'))
```

but this gives me the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument
```

Why? I would like to understand this more.

Comment: This is what I suspect, but what I did not confirm: uuid.uuid4() does not return bytes, but `UUID` object. Thus the encoder cannot properly handle it as this object might not have default string presentation anymore.

Comment: You haven't given enough of a traceback for the first error to be useful

Comment: Some useful answers that really helped my understanding thank you.

Comment: Helpful reference: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html?highlight=bytes#byte-string-literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base64.b64encode takes bytes as argument, no need to decode-re-encode.

```
>>> base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
b'58jvz9F7QXaulSScqus0NA=='
>>> base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
b'gLV2vn/1RMSSckMd647jUg=='
```

Comment: but this would not take the actual UUID but the byte representation, right?

Comment: @OrbiterFleet yes, which is the actual UUID. Also your original code in python2 did that (and the slice at 22. byte).

Comment: Yep sorry the code did do that with ``uuid.uuid4().bytes``. I understand now!

Comment: The confusion stems usually from the fact that `str` in python2 is `bytes`, aka strings in python2 are byte strings, and you have to do extra to get unicode, like `u"stuff"` literals and `unicode(stuff)` calls. It takes some practice to understand the difference, but it's worth it, at least in my opinion :P (since we have to handle weird chars like ä and å all the time).

Comment: Last question and I'm making this as accepted. Did I also misunderstand  what ``uuid.uuid4()`` returns, I assumed it would return a string (or byte string as you said) however the function returns i.e. ``UUID('c75e94b7-964e-4d2f-ae18-be712f13f968')``

Comment: Yes, it is an UUID object wrapping the actual byte representation, like @Mohammadhzp points out. It offers helpful methods for inspecting and using the value.

Comment: cool so if I wanted the actual UUID string I do ``str(uuid.uuid4())``  or `` the_edcoded.decode("utf-8")``. byte string I do ``uuid.uuid4().bytes``.  and b64encode only takes ``byte strings``. think that all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> type(uuid.uuid4())
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

This shows that uuid.uuid4() is not a string and you need to pass an string to bytes, so here is the working code:

```
base64.b64encode(bytes(str(uuid.uuid4()), 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: OK good that makes sense. But why do we need ``bytes(`` if as in @Ilja answer b64encode takes bytes as argument. I would have guess that ``base64.b64encode(str(uuid.uuid4()), 'utf-8')`` should have worked but I get the error ``'str' does not support the buffer interface``

Comment: Your question was about why this code is not working and I want to understand it more, I answered it's because you are passing an object instead of a string to bytes(), the other answer is certainly better but my answer is the correct reply for your question,base64::b64encode() expect parameter one to be bytes not a string and does not take utf-8 for second parameter so base64.b64encode(str(uuid.uuid4()), 'utf-8') must not work

Comment: I voted this answer up, not sue why others voted it down. maybe someone else could reply I'm interested also.

Comment: the second part of your answer tho takes a string uuid and gives a different  result to mine using ``uuid.uuid4().bytes``. I could be wrong but its taking the string value and retuning that into a byte string, right?

Comment: No, byte string is different, in this case, bytes() knows this is a string which turns into bytes, bytes() is useful for ASCII characters which means it's ok in here, you get different result because byte order in uuid.UUID().bytes is big-endian(my best guess)